# Different color after bottom line

Tags: emacs, color-scheme

I'm a vim user trying to feel at home in Emacs. I really like the different color for the null lines at the bottom I have in vim, like in this image:

[image]

I tried messing around with the `set-face-background` of Emacs but I haven't find an equivalent option for this.

How can I achieve this customization in Emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `whitespace-mode` to highlight various invisible characters and boundaries. See also "Fringes" and "Displaying Boundaries" in Emacs Info.

Comment: I used the fringes bitmap to mark the null lines. I couldn't figure out how to change the colors though, but the bitmap works for me. Thanks

Comment: @Jesse: `set-face-foreground` `fringe` `red` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I meant the color of the whole line the fringe is in, not just the fringe

Comment: Maybe `set-variable` `indicate-unused-lines` `t` might be interesting for you.